# Three.js DecalGeometry is not a constructor

Tags: three.js

I've installed and imported three.js as a module (v0.100.0) like:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
...
var d = new THREE.DecalGeometry(. . .);
```

Getting error message that DecalGeometry is not a constructor.
Looking in src directory for the three module, there is no DecalGeometry anywhere. What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THREE.DecalGeometry` is not part of the core but of the examples directory. You have to include the module manually into your project via:

```js
import { DecalGeometry } from 'three/addons/geometries/DecalGeometry.js';
```